# AG Listener goes offline during comms link failure

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, windows-server

I wanted to try and get some clarity on some behavior we recently experienced with a number of our production clusters during an event where we lost both communication links.

Ours clusters span two sites on different subnets and are a mixture of 2 and 4 nodes. During the incident we lost all network comms between Site A and Site B, and because of this a number of our AGs across production had their listener taken offline.

The issue with the impacted clusters appears to be due to the Cluster Group being owned by a node in Site B rather than Site A where the AG Primary nodes were. I would have expected the AGs on the 4 node clusters to have remained online so I'm trying to confirm why this was the issue?

I'm suspecting the witness had an issue because from its standpoint Site B would have also been healthy.

Unfortunately I don't have the Cluster logs from the event but below is a summary of what was seen in the logs (Cluster 1 AG went offline & Cluster 2 remained online):

**Cluster 1**
4:04:22 pm
SiteB Node 1 Removes both SiteA nodes (Lost comms)
SiteB Node 2 Removes both SiteA nodes (Lost comms)

4:04:24 pm
SiteA Node 1 Removes both SiteB nodes (Lost comms)
SiteA Node 2 Removes both SiteB nodes (Lost comms)

4:04:30 pm
SiteA Node 1 tries to start the cluster but doesn’t have latest copy of cluster config (Presume that, as you said, cluster resource was hosted on an SiteB node)
SiteA Node 2 Removes SiteA Node 1 (Lost comms)
SiteA Node 2 shuts down cluster service because it can’t make quorum (No comms to SiteA nodes and no comms to SiteB Node 1)

4:04:38 pm
SiteA Node 2 tries to start the cluster but doesn’t have latest copy of cluster config (Presume that, as you said, cluster resource was hosted on an SiteB node)
SiteA Node 2 IP address fails

**Cluster 2**
4:03:17 pm
SiteB Node 1 Removes both SiteA nodes (Lost comms)
SiteB Node 2 Removes both SiteA nodes (Lost comms)
SiteA Node 1 Removes both SiteB nodes (Lost comms)
SiteA Node 2 Removes both SiteB nodes (Lost comms)

4:03:23 pm
SiteB Node 1 tries to start the cluster but doesn’t have latest copy of cluster config (Presume that, as you said, cluster resource was hosted on an SiteA node)
SiteB Node 2 tries to start the cluster but doesn’t have latest copy of cluster config (Presume that, as you said, cluster resource was hosted on an SiteA node)
SiteB Node 1 cluster Resource Hosting Subsystem (RHS) termintates

4:03:34 pm
SiteB Node 2 Removes SiteB Node 1 (Lost comms, presumably because subsystem was terminated on SiteB Node 1)
SiteB Node 1 shuts down cluster service because it can’t make quorum (No comms to SiteA nodes and no comms to SiteB Node 1)

4:03:43 pm
SiteB Node 2 tries to start the cluster but doesn’t have latest copy of cluster config (Presume that, as you said, cluster resource was hosted on an SiteA node)

Some entries from the cluster log on the primary site that might be relevant:

00000f10.000068a8::2024/01/10-16:04:30.133 INFO  223:223:565934: Arbitration has occured updating paxos tag
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.133 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Reading file share witness epoch data.
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.133 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Re-arbitrating for file share witness since lock is currently released.
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.136 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Opening file \FSW.fdqn\sql_quorum$\PSYSQLCL01\c34ae4ce-b89f-4f8c-83be-c39dcb00300e\Witness.log.
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.139 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Attempting to lock file \FSW.fdqn\sql_quorum$\PSYSQLCL01\c34ae4ce-b89f-4f8c-83be-c39dcb00300e\Witness.log, try 1 of 30.
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.139 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Succeeded in locking file \FSW.fdqn\sql_quorum$\PSYSQLCL01\c34ae4ce-b89f-4f8c-83be-c39dcb00300e\Witness.log
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.148 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Read 88 bytes from the witness file share.
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.151 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Releasing temporary lock on witness file share.
00000f10.000068a8::2024/01/10-16:04:30.151 INFO  [QUORUM] Node 4 CompareAndSetWitnessTag: reading witness tag.
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.151 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Reading file share witness epoch data.
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.151 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Re-arbitrating for file share witness since lock is currently released.
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.157 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Opening file \FSW.fdqn\sql_quorum$\PSYSQLCL01\c34ae4ce-b89f-4f8c-83be-c39dcb00300e\Witness.log.
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.157 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Attempting to lock file \FSW.fdqn\sql_quorum$\PSYSQLCL01\c34ae4ce-b89f-4f8c-83be-c39dcb00300e\Witness.log, try 1 of 30.
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.157 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Succeeded in locking file \FSW.fdqn\sql_quorum$\PSYSQLCL01\c34ae4ce-b89f-4f8c-83be-c39dcb00300e\Witness.log
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.167 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Read 88 bytes from the witness file share.
00002490.00003a74::2024/01/10-16:04:30.169 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Releasing temporary lock on witness file share.
00000f10.000068a8::2024/01/10-16:04:30.170 INFO  [QUORUM] Node 4 CompareAndSetWitnessTag: Attempting to update witness tag (224:224:565932) to 223:223:565934.
00000f10.000068a8::2024/01/10-16:04:30.170 WARN  [QUORUM] Node 4 CompareAndSetWitnessTag: witness tag (224:224:565932) is better than proposed tag (223:223:565934).
00000f10.000068a8::2024/01/10-16:04:30.170 INFO  [QUORUM] Node 4 CompareAndSetWitnessTag: releasing witness share lock
00002490.00006c5c::2024/01/10-16:04:30.170 INFO  [RES] File Share Witness : Ignoring request to release witness share because it is not currently locked.
00000f10.000068a8::2024/01/10-16:04:30.170 WARN  Arbitration failed with error code 995, not emitting QuorumArbitratred message
00000f10.000068a8::2024/01/10-16:04:30.170 ERR   Shutting down because arbitration failed (status = 5925)
00000f10.000068a8::2024/01/10-16:04:30.170 INFO  [NETFT] Cluster Service preterminate succeeded.
00000f10.000068a8::2024/01/10-16:04:30.170 INFO  [NETFT] Disabling heartbeats
00002490.00002444::2024/01/10-16:04:30.170 WARN  [RHS] Cluster service has terminated. Cluster.Service.Running.Event got signaled.
00002adc.00002ae0::2024/01/10-16:04:30.170 WARN  [RHS] Cluster service has terminated. Cluster.Service.Running.Event got signaled.
00002448.000025b4::2024/01/10-16:04:30.170 WARN  [RHS] Cluster service has terminated. Cluster.Service.Running.Event got signaled.

The file share witnesses are located on a file share on a separate server in a different location. According to our network team connectivity to the witness server was up during the incident.

Any input on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add what the witness is, where it lives, how it is configured and any relevant information from the cluster log such as the quorum lost events from both sides of the partitioned cluster.

Comment: Hi Sean - I've added some additional comments above.

Comment: Is the FSW sitting on DFS or DFSR or anything? Seems odd both sides would say they don't have the latest copy, which is what should come from reading the paxos tag info from the witness.

Comment: No we don't have the FWS sitting on DFS or DFSR. I agree it does seem strange.